# Trigger a function in PHP when a new row is inserted in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database in phpmyadmin which stores users. I need to call a PHP function which will get the newly inserted user values and send them in a POST request to an API.
So whenever a new user gets inserted into the database I need to get the values and send them to an API. If after that a new user gets inserted into the database I need to call the function and send the values again.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 1
```

This just gets me the last inserted value in the database, but it doesn't trigger the POST request to the API

Comment: I do something similar with orders. I added a status flag to the orders table with the values: "new", "updated" and "sent". I send new and changed orders to the API regularly using [a cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and only set the "sent" status when the updates have really been received.

Comment: this will get you the last inserted user, fine, you need to add php code afterwards to send the data by POST, by your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put php code after insert row to your table `users` smth like this:

```
<?php 

public function handle()
{
    // save to database
    $dataBaseManager->inertNewUser($userData);
    // and after this insert put your api call
    // prepare data if needed ...

    $someApiHandler->sendNewUserData($userData);
}
```